# How to delete objects in c++?

Tags: c++, directx

I have a pointer created where by

```
    Shell* shell = new Shell();
```

initialised it by

```
    if (!shellTexture->initialize(graphics, SHELL_IMAGE))
    throw(GameError(gameErrorNS::FATAL_ERROR, "Error initializing shell texture"));
    if (!shell->initialize(this, ShellNS::WIDTH, ShellNS::HEIGHT, ShellNS::TEXTURE_COLS, shellTexture))
    throw(GameError(gameErrorNS::FATAL_ERROR, "Error initializing shell game object"));
```

and

```
    shell.draw();
```

and i want to destroy the shell when upon it colliding with my player.
I want to spawn it as well every x seconds.

I did not use any arrays or vectors to store the objects in it.

```
    delete shell;
```

crashes the program upon it colliding with my player in

```
   if (shell->collidesWith(*player,collisionVector))
{
   delete shell;
   //and damage player
   }
```

how do you delete the shell?

What is the simplest way to implement this so that i am able to clear it from the memory and yet able to re-initialise the shell to be there?

edit: im a real noob at pointers

Comment: Without a [MCVE] it is hard to say. But the syntax in your question is correct.

Comment: So what is the problem *exactly*?

Comment: These two lines by themselves would work fine. So what else are you doing with the pointer?

Comment: @YuriyIvaskevych i am unable to delete the object properly without the game crashing.

Comment: Post more code.

Comment: @user7194060 Than check maybe you still use deleted pointer somewhere, because you haven't provided the piece of code where it crashes (can be figured out using debugger).

Comment: @user7194060  It looks like this statement is executed after shell  was deleted  if (shell.collidesWith(player,collisionVector)) And why is not there used operator ->?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow my bad, i have changed it.

Comment: After you delete, you could set `shell` to null so that you can check for whether you currently have an object (and if not, you re-initialize one).

Comment: Smart pointers instead of raw owning pointer would even be better.

Comment: @Jarod42 what are smart pointers? sorry im bad

Comment: Look at [Smart_pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer).

Comment: @user7194060 How are you using `shell.draw()`? if your shell is a pointer it should be `shell->draw()`.  With the code you have provided this question can't be answered because we can't see exactly everywhere your using shell, and if your properly checking if shell is a valid pointer or not.

Comment: You should really consider using a C++ smart-pointer like ``std::unique_ptr`` or (rarely) ``std::shared_ptr``. Manually memory clean-up in C++ is highly error-prone and difficult to debug. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh279674.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
type ptr = new type(args);
```

(1) allocates sufficient memory to hold an object of type `type`, (2) creates an object of type `type` by calling its constructor with the arguments `args`, and (3) assigns the memory address of the object created to the pointer `ptr`.

You can then use the object created via its address stored in `ptr`, for example `ptr->member_function(args)`. Conversely, the line

```
delete ptr;
```

attempts to (1) call the destructor for the object of `type` and (2) de-allocate the memory associated with that object. It **does not alter the value of `ptr`**, i.e. after deletion, the pointer becomes a **dangling pointer**: its value (an address) does no longer refer to that of a valid object.

As a consequence, attempts to use a dangling pointer, e.g. via `ptr->member_function(args)` are ill-formed and most likely **crash the program**. Likewise, calling

```
delete ptr;
```

**again** on an already deleted pointer are ill-formed and likely **crash the program** too. In order to avoid such ill-formed code, you may set the `ptr` to null after deletion, i.e.

```
delete ptr;
ptr = nullptr;
```

when (1) you can easily verify whether `ptr` is still valid (conversion to bool obtains false only for `nullptr`) and (2) avoid the issue of double deletion, as

```
delete nullptr;
```

is harmless (does nothing).

---

*Edit*. In your case, `type`=`Shell` and `ptr`=`shell`, i.e. your variable `shell` is the pointer to a `Shell`.

Note also that it is generally recommended to avoid using `delete` (and even `new`) and instead use smart pointers, such as [`std::unique_ptr<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), which will automatically `delete` the object pointed to when they go out of scope, enabling exception safe code without memory leaks.

Comment: does this mean that i have to add another line of code of `Shell shelladdr;` and `shell=&shelladdr;` cause i have not done that

Comment: If you have `Shell shelladdr; Shell *shell = &shelladdr;  delete shell;` then it'll crash just because you're trying to delete static variable. It wasn't allocated by new.